# Необходимо вставить в список на позицию с индексом k элемент, равный C

Tags: python, python-3.x

Прохожу курс по python. Тема 2 списки и цикл for.
Задание следующее:

> Дан список целых чисел, число k и значение C. Необходимо вставить в список на позицию с индексом k элемент, равный C, сдвинув все элементы имевшие индекс не менее k вправо.
>
> Посколько при этом количество элементов в списке увеличивается, после
>   считывания списка в его конец нужно будет добавить новый элемент,
>   используя метод append.
>
> Вставку необходимо осуществлять уже в считанном списке, не делая этого
>    при выводе и не создавая дополнительного списка.
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

моя попытка:

```
s=list(input([]))
k=int(input())
C=input()
s[k:k]=C
print(s)
```

не проходит

мой скрипт выдаёт 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как переместить все элементы? *Done*
Как вывести не лист, а значения? *Done*
Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе, мы вводили эл-ты в одну строку? *Done:)*

Comment: И что же вам выдает интерпретатор python?

Comment: Он выполняет как нужно(по всей видимости не так), но задачу мне засчитывают частичным решением..http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=16876#1

Comment: Если вы вдруг решили, что у всех пользователей ru.SO есть доступ к http://informatics.mccme.ru вы ошиблись. Что значит "_засчитывает частным решением_"? Что именно выдает ваш python скрипт? И как его поведение отличается от желаемого?

Comment: Не ошибается тот, кто ничего не делает :)
мой скрипт :  вставляет на место k элемент C и автоматически сдвигает все эл-ты списка. По всей видимости, нужно каким то образом сначала сдвинуть все эл-ты с индексом k и более, и потом вставлять значение. А еще нужно вывести не сам список, а значения оттуда(?)

Comment: Еще раз. Что именно _выдает ваш скрипт_?

Comment: Судя по приведенной картинке, ваш скрипт выдает ровно то, _что и должен выдавать_ (за исключением форматирования массива при выводе). В чем проблема-то?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не понимаю причем здесь attend и как вывести не список, а его значения.. А еще как поместить вводимые элементы на одну строку

Comment: Вот именно эти вопросы вам и нужно задавать ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, поереформулируем ответ...

1. считываем строку с целыми числами, разделенными любым количеством пробельных символов

   `line = input()
   list_of_numbers = [int(item) for item in line.split()]`

   или в одну строку

   `list_of_numbers = [int(item) for item in input().split()]`
2. Добавляем элемент new_element в список на позицию index тремя способами:

a)

```
list_of_numbers.insert(index, new_element)
```

b)

```
list_of_numbers[index:index] = new_element
```

c)

```
length = len(list_of_numbers)
list_of_numbers.append(None)
for i in range(length, index, -1):
    list_of_numbers[i] = list_of_numbers[i-1]
list_of_numbers[index] = new_element
```

список нужно проходить именно с конца, чтобы не затирать предыдущим кждый последующий элемент списка.

3. Выводим список поэлементно:

a) с переводом строки

```
for item in list_of_numbers:
    print item # python 2.x
    print(item) # python 3.x
```

b) без перевода строки

```
for item in list_of_numbers:
    print item, # python 2.x
    print(item, end="") # python 3.x
```

4. Учимся пользоваться крайне удобной встроенной справкой python прямо в консоли

   `some_list = []`

   `dir(some_list)`

выводит все методы, имеющиеся у объекта some_list

```
help(some_list.some_method)
```

выводит справку по конкретному методу

Comment: А можно все тоже самое сделать в python way: `a[4:4] = [0, 1, 2]`. Только проблема у ТС совсем не в этом.

Comment: Уж куда более Python way чем `a.insert(4, value)`... А угадывать, какой именно способ хотят получить от ТС, увольте-с.

Comment: Вот и я говорю, что ТС сначала должен нормально сформулировать вопрос ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Ваш способ нужен, чтобы всавить несколько значений, мой очевиднее, если вставить нужно одно значение. TMTOWDI )

Comment: Почитайте комментарии к вопросу. А заодно и обновленный вопрос. У ТС нет проблем со вставкой значений ))

Comment: Ну, я привел способ с `for` и `append`...

Comment: С каждой правкой ответ менялся от издевки до практически полноценного ответа. Я понятия не имел, что можно было добавлять пустое значение, спасибо. Еще вопрос, а почему мы с конца списка шли? Нельзя было добавить элемент и в цикле делать [i+1]. И даже после всех этих правок решение только частичное..

Comment: @ВитяАлександрович, дописал в ответе. Извините, если показалось издевкой, но городить велосипеды, подменяющие даже не средтсва стандартной библиотеки, а встроенные средсва языка - очень плохая идея, вообще говоря. Т.е. в реальной задаче, то ТОЛЬКО Ваш способ, или мой, который с `l.insert`